# object not found error in r when using sum

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, tidyverse, knitr

I have been trying to produce some visualizations using a dataset. I first added some new columns to the dataframe:

```
ads <- ads %>% mutate(estimated_audience_size_mean = round(rowMeans(ads[,17:18]), -1),
                      impressions_mean = round(rowMeans(ads[,19:20]), -1),
                      spend_mean = round(rowMeans(ads[,21:22]), -1))
```

Now, when I view ads from the environment tab, I can see the three new columns created. However, when I try running the code below, I get the following error

```
pages <- ads %>%
   group_by(page_name) %>%
   sum(spend_mean) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   arrange(desc(n)) %>%
   slice(1:15)
```

I get the following error:

> object 'spend_mean' not found

I have tried installing operators library followed by magrittr. And replaced %>% with |>. Also replaced page_name and spend_mean with ads$page_name and ads$spend_mean. But nothing seems to work. How can I make the second code of chunk work?

Comment: Wrap your `sum(spend_mean)` in a call to `mutate`. At the moment, R doesn’t know that you want to look in the `ads` data frame to find the column. Your title is misleading because you are *not* using `mutate` when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As shared by Limey in the comments, wrapping the sum function in mutate did the trick.

```
pages <- ads %>%
  group_by(page_name) %>%
  mutate(page_spend_mean = sum(spend_mean)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(page_spend_mean)) %>%
  slice(1:15)
```